# Can Latex plot these set of simultaneous equations or is too big?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am currently working on Overleaf and trying to plot the system of equations:

```
7x + y <= 10000
10x + 2y > 13000
```

I do have the code for plotting a set of equations which I got from an answer to another question

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
% grid
\draw [densely dashed, gray!50]    (-6,-6) grid (6,6);  
% ticks
\foreach \i in {-5,...,-1,1,2,...,5}
{
\draw (\i,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below,font=\scriptsize] {$\i$};
\draw (0.1,\i) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left, font=\scriptsize] {$\i$};
}
% axis
\draw [->] ( 0,-6) -- (0,6) node [left ] {$y$};
\draw [->] (-6, 0) -- (6,0) node [below] {$x$};
% graph
\draw [draw=red,thick] (-2,-6) -- (2,6);
\fill[red] (-1,-3) circle (1.5mm) (1,3) circle (1.5mm);
\draw [draw=blue]   (-6,-5) -- (6,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I have tried editing the values to suit my system of equations. However, LaTeX crashes because it cannot print objects above 19 ft?

I don't understand why this should be an issue as the scale can always be adjusted.

I was looking for an answer on whether it is possible to use this method to graph my system of equations. If yes, what are the requisite changes that I need to make? And if not, is there any other way in which I can plot these equations?

Comment: Can you post the solution which crashes please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: All numbers that are in your calculations or can be the result during the calculating process **must not** exceed 16383.99999 at any point. That is because TeX is not quite good at handling big numbers.

Comment: @Fractalisattopanswers.xyz, that answers my question, thanks. I'll just use another method then. Which is a shame because the ticks and grid looked very aesthetically pleasing on my paper.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Note that if you face the 19ft (5.7m) limit, it means that your plot contains control point or parts that are this large. This is a hard limitation of TeX itself, not of Overleaf.

Comment: @SushrutaNandy it’s like you use 1/1000000000*1000000000. The result is only 1, but TeX has to compute up to 1000000000.